# Java SIP - Suggest me SDK or API working in 2020

Tags: open-source, java, voip, sdk

Can you kindly suggest me which Java SIP CLIENT should I use to make a Softphone desktop application. I really need to know it. I have worked on peers java sip desktop, but can't add hold and transfer method in it. As technology has grown, there should be at least another easy to integrate java sip client library for desktop.

Comment: What requirements are you needing? What is that application supposed to do?

Comment: And is it OK if it stops working in 2021? How much may it cost? Any license considerations?

Comment: I just want to create a basic SIP application, I already have the proper credentials of sip account. But, I need to create a application for my client, which can dial,hold and all those specifications. Thus I need your recommendations.

Comment: Put the details of your requirements into the question.  Use the edit button.

Comment: Done, kindly check it now, I have clarified it a little bit more.